# How to get the fractional part of a product of large numbers with machine precision?

Tags: floating-point, fractional-part

Let us have about 100 or so random (exact) floats such as:

$$ A_1 = 1234123.428\\
A_2 = 13713.4193\\
A_3 = 0.1332\\
A_4 = 123.13213\\
...$$

Now I want to find an efficient way to get the fractional part of:

$A_1 \times A_2 \times A_3 ..... \times A_n$

to within 4 digits, say. Is there an efficient algorithm to do this? Note, that we can't simply multiply all the numbers together because we assume we are using machine precision floating point math only is accurate to say 10 significant figures and so the fractional part would be lost.

Edit: We are assuming the floats $A_1$ are exact. Also, we know we could use some BigNumber library to multiply all the values to exact precision and then look at the fractional part. But I'm looking for a more efficient algorithm (if one exists). Perhaps using some simplifications using modular arithmetic.

Comment: What is your measure of efficiency? Why do you think using a BigNumber library will be inefficient?

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure. I was hoping there might be a trick.

Comment: The obvious trick is to use a BigNumber library (which comes at zero cost in many programming languages). Why have you rejected it?

Comment: @Rob I just assumed it would be slow for say 100 numbers and I want to do something like this many times so efficiency is key. Also, just by doing the multiplications one would be keeping too much precision at each step. But one could round up I suppose.

Comment: From many years of experience, I advise you not to design software on the basis of unmeasurable mantra like "efficiency is key" or woolly thoughts like "I just assumed that ... would be too slow". Do some software engineering and find out what performance requirements you have to meet and do some experiments to see how a package like GnuMP will perform on your problem. Come back to MSE, if that leaves you with a problem that the technology won't solve but maths might.

Comment: While Robert Israel's answer settles your question, I am curious about your motivation. When is the ability to compute the fractional part of a product useful? Would you add some words about your application? It is entirely possible that your real problem can be solved by some other means.

Answer (score 0):

It is even worse than that.  The fractional part is not even well defined.  Your $A_1$ is of order $10^7$ so there is uncertainty of the order of $10^{-3}$, which means the last place could be wrong.  Now if I just square $A_1$ and represent the error by $\delta$ we have $(A_1+\delta)^2\approx A_1^2+2\delta A_1$.  The leading term is of order $10^{14}$ and $\delta A_1$ is of order $10^4$.  Even if we can do this square exactly the input data accuracy says we do not know the four digits in front of the decimal point, let alone the fractional part.

If you want to take your input data as exact, you can certainly implement a multiple precision multiply, multiply accurately enough to make sure you have the digits right, and take the fractional part.  I don't think there is anything better.

Answer (score 0):

If the product is greater than about $10^{6}$, and the input data are only $10$-digit approximations of some true values, then you don't have enough information to determine the fractional part to the required accuracy.

If you assume the input data are exact, you can do exact rational arithmetic.